# Redundant If message

Tags: java, netbeans

I have my Fraction program running smooth but the NetBeans IDE is telling me the following `if` is redundant:

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
  Fraction bool = (Fraction) other;

  if(this.numerator == bool.numerator && this.denominator == bool.denominator)
  {
   return true;
  }
  else return false;       
}
```

The above code compiles / runs perfectly and passes all the test cases but the redundant flag by NetBeans is really bothering me. I add `reduceToLowestTerms()` to my code and the flag goes away but I already have `reduceToLowestTerms()` in my constructor. This is what the non-redundant code (according to NetBeans ) looks like:

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
        Fraction bool = (Fraction) other;

        if(this.numerator == bool.numerator && this.denominator == bool.denominator)
        {
         bool.reduceToLowestTerms();
         this.reduceToLowestTerms();
         return true;
        }
         else return false;       
    }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure it's saying the `if` is redundant, not the `else` ?

Comment: What does `reduceToLowestTerms()` do?  The only `Fraction` class I can find is in apache common-lang, and it doesn't have that method, so I'm assuming this is some custom fraction class you've written?

Comment: Could you post the Fraction class too?

Comment: maybe it's because `return (this.numerator == bool.numerator && this.denominator == bool.denominator)` would work without an explicit if-else. just a guess.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So put it back,. This is not a Java error or warning message.

Comment: @EJP: was going to do that when you beat me to it. My bad. Eclipse/Java doesn't send me this message in my tests, hence my deleted comment, and (almost) re-added tag. To the OP, sorry for my error. You were right.

Comment: Curious. Netbeans has no business introducing side-effects into an `equals()` method.

Comment: @EJP I don't think NetBeans introduced the side-effect. The OP noticed that when he/she introduced the side effect, the flag went away.

Answer (score 8):

This appears similar to a warning my IDE gives on this statement:

> 'if' statement can be simplified
>
> ```
> if(foo())
> {
>    return true;
> }
> else
> {
>    return false;
> }
> ```
>
> can be simplified to
>
> ```
> return foo();
> ```

It's just overly complicated and verbose code.  Your simplification would be:

```
return this.numerator == bool.numerator && this.denominator == bool.denominator;
```

But as you've noticed, your code is already correct.  It's not necessary to make this change, but it will make the code more concise and more simplified.

The reason that adding calls to another method (`reduceToLowestTerms()`) removes this "flag" is that the code can no longer be simplified in this way to a single `return` statement.